# Convert a list to map and merge values terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to convert a list of items into a map.
The key will match a key in the item and the value should create a list of appends to the list if the key already exist.

Maybe an example will be more understable

```
variable "list" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [
    { a : "a", k : "k1" },
    { a : "b", k : "k1" },
    { a : "c", k : "k1" },
    { a : "d", k : "k2" },
    { a : "e", k : "k2" }
  ]
}
    
// Output wanted
// {
//  "k1" : [{a: "a"}, {a: "b"}, {a: "c"}],
//  "k2" : [{a: "d"}, {a: "e"}]
// }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the following:

```
variable "list" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [
    { a : "a", k : "k1" },
    { a : "b", k : "k1" },
    { a : "c", k : "k1" },
    { a : "d", k : "k2" },
    { a : "e", k : "k2" }
  ]
}

output "test" {

  value = {for item in var.list:
            item["k"] => {a = item["a"]}...
          }
}
```

The above code uses [three dots](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/function-calls.html#expanding-function-arguments) operator and it produces:

```
test = {
  "k1" = [
    {
      "a" = "a"
    },
    {
      "a" = "b"
    },
    {
      "a" = "c"
    },
  ]
  "k2" = [
    {
      "a" = "d"
    },
    {
      "a" = "e"
    },
  ]
}
```